# c# datagridview checkbox check if other column value is 0

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have DataGridView with a CheckBox Column(Header: Status) and Textbox Column(Header: Quantity). I want to check automatically the checkbox column if the quantity is 0.

[image]

Comment: @ethorn10 I am only a student.. my professor taught only basic in c#.. I research and try this since nov 2015 but I can't do it.. that's why I asked here
(sorry to my english I hope u will understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the rows if the datagridview like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    //Check Column 3 for quantity        
    if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "0")
    {   
        //Get checkbox in column 1 and cast it to a checkbox
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;     
        cell.Value = cell.TrueValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Big Thanks to you!!    there's an error at cell.Value == cell.TrueValue;    but i remove the one = (equal sign) and it works.. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: Sir.. do you know how to save that into access database?   the checkbox checked in datagridview but didn't save into access dbase.. I use Update statement but it didn't work

Comment: Sure I can help you with that but I need to see your code. Just edit your question and add your new code so I can see it.